# How to retrieve the last characters from a remote text file using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to get the digits from the second last column in this txt file 
url: http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/wing-kp.txt

I only need the last value in the second last column at the very end of the file.

I have tried a few different sample-codes in Python 3(.4?)

This code only get me a specific amount of characters starting from the beginning of the file:

```
# coding: utf-8
import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.Request('http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/wing-kp.txt')
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
 the_page = response.read(100)
print (the_page)
```

I have tried the .seek function but it returned a value I could not recognize.

In the following code I first tried to use the .seek directly from the webpage, but it didn't work so then I tried to save the file first and then read from the file with no/limited success.

```
# coding: utf-8

import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.Request('http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/wing-kp.txt')
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   open('data.txt', 'wb').write(urllib.request.urlopen(req).read())


file = open('data.txt' , 'rb+')
data = file.seek(-5, 2)
file.close()
print (data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need the second last value, you could do it like this:

```
file = open('data.txt' , 'rb+')
data = file.readlines()
file.close()
data = [i for i in str(data[-1]).strip().split(" ") if i != ''][-2]
```

With `file.readlines()` we get a list of all the lines, where we can take the last by indexing with `[-1]`. Then, we can simply split by whitespaces and construct a new list with all non-empty strings, where we now have the second last column as the second last element of the list. This assumes that there are no whitespaces **in** the values for the last two columns and does not work for parsing all columns, since other data like the dates is also separated by whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and good description! It is just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Using `requests` rather than `urllib`. Assumes that you don't need the file on disk:

```
import requests
url = "http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/wing-kp.txt"
data = [x for x in requests.get(url).content.rstrip().split("\n")[-1].split(" ") if x][-2]
```

Command line version because why not? :)

```
$ python -c 'import requests; print [x for x in requests.get("http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/wing-kp.txt").content.rstrip().split("\n")[-1].split(" ") if x][-2]'
2.33
```